# How to train Bard to answer based on a private FAQ document?

Tags: bard, knowledge-base, chat

I have a private (unpublished) FAQ document about an app, it has 7000 words and 40000 characters. To simulate it you may try taking https://github.com/ankidroid/Anki-Android/wiki/FAQ and replacing the app's name with another name.

I would like to train Bard to answer questions about it.

Are there ways/tricks to achieve that? Or do I need some other software in coordination with Bard?

Ideally it should be able to answer questions correctly even if they are asked differently, and not hallucinate or not too much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The model behind Bard is [PaLM 2](https://ai.google/discover/palm2/) which can be accessed through the [PaLM API](https://developers.generativeai.google/products/palm) - currently on a waitlist system.

The model is not available for training or fine-tuning, but the API allows you to [generate embeddings](https://developers.generativeai.google/api/python/google/generativeai/generate_embeddings) for text, so a **document retrieval** approach to allowing PaLM to answer questions about it would be possible, as described here: https://genai.stackexchange.com/a/33/8

Specifically, for determining chunk size and amount to include in the prompt, PaLM 2 has a context window of 8000 tokens, [approximately 32000 characters](https://developers.generativeai.google/models/language#model_metadata)

---

Be aware that by submitting content to Bard, [you give Google](https://developers.generativeai.google/terms#content_license) "a perpetual, irrevocable, worldwide, sublicensable, royalty-free, and non-exclusive license" to "provide, improve, and develop products, services, and machine learning technologies." This may be a concern for your private unpublished document.