# Does Llama2 LLMs have real time data?

Tags: llm, gpt, llama-2

Meta released their open source LLM, Llama 2. Does Llama 2 have real time data or this was trained on data available till some date?

Comment: Welcome to [genai.se]. Should this question be posed to the community? Have you attempted to find the answer on the Meta (Meta Platforms Inc.) announcement or Llama 2 documentation?

Answer (score 8):

According to Llama 2's [model card](https://github.com/facebookresearch/llama/blob/main/MODEL_CARD.md):

> The pretraining data has a cutoff of September 2022, but some tuning data is more recent, up to July 2023

Llama 2 is provided as a downloadable model, rather than an online service, so the model won't be continuously updated with real-time data. There are however [ways you could teach it new knowledge without re-training from scratch.](https://genai.stackexchange.com/q/24/8)

Comment: Could you please explain what does *“tuning data”* mean in this context?

Comment: @A.L LLMs are pre-trained with a huge quantity of arbitrary text on a self-supervised task (generally predicting the next token). To specialise it to a desired task, such as helpfully answering user questions, the model can then be "fine-tuned" by training on a smaller quantity of data (maybe labelled/curated) - in Llama 2's case "publicly available instruction datasets, as well as over one million new human-annotated examples". Tuning data would be that smaller set of task-specific data.

Answer (score 2):

Most likely pre-trained however, some interfaces allow input from web searches e.g. https://huggingface.co/chat/ allows to search web with your input as well as utilise it's pre-trained data.

I also found this: https://github.com/facebookresearch/llama/blob/main/MODEL_CARD.md

Which states: "Data Freshness The pretraining data has a cutoff of September 2022, but some tuning data is more recent, up to July 2023."