# GPT-4 to Generate USMLE Exam Questions

Tags: gpt, fine-tuning

I have a set of example multiple choice questions on the USMLE, a US medical licensing exam.

I want to use the set of questions, their answers, and the explanations associated with the correct answers to fine-tune GPT-4 to be able to generate new exam questions. I would also like to fine tune it on a textbook associated with the exam.

How would I go about doing this? Would it be as simple as finetuning through the GPT-4 platform?

Edit: I realize GPT-4 fine tuning is not yet available. How would this work in GPT-3? Would langchain integration be useful, and if so how?

Comment: That is not possible as yet. OpenAi has said that they [don't have fine tuning](https://help.openai.com/en/articles/7127982-can-i-fine-tune-on-gpt-4) for gpt4 as yet.

Comment: OK. How would it work through GPT-3?

Comment: You can use [gpt4 with document retrieval](https://genai.stackexchange.com/a/33/145) or you can have [gpt3.5 fine tuned](https://platform.openai.com/docs/guides/fine-tuning).

Comment: Please improve the writing of this question. Consider that this isn't a discussion forum, so question comments eventually might be deleted. Also, remember that posts on this platform have a revision history, so there is no need to label changes as "edits".

Comment: That depends: do you need the answers and explanations to be correct, or not?  I tried it with a different subject and question format (short-answer rather than multiple-choice), and the result was slower and less accurate than the previous fully-manual process.

Answer (score 0):

1. Give a few pages from the textbook as part of the prompt, and ask GPT to generate a multiple choice question on it (choices + correct answer(s) + explanation).
2. If MCQs don't look good, try in-context learning or finetuning by giving MCQ examples.